# How to cover a window well seamlessly so I can project TV onto that wall?

Tags: walls, windows, home-theater

Problem: I would like the projected image to cover the whole wall, but when I turn the projector on, the window is in the way.

I bought a small screen (see the photographs) to try and cover that up, but it doesn't blend in perfectly and you can clearly see some shadows (depending on the angle you're looking at it from) and outlines in the screen, so this solution won't work.

The WHOLE wall is actually pretty much covered by the projection, but the wall plugs are not a problem.

I thought of maybe using some foam, but I am afraid it might not have the flattest surface, but I think I'll give it a try.

What do you think?

Here are pictures:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Could you not just simply cover your entire wall with a projection screen? Seems like the most 'practical' solution here.

Comment: no, the projection would be much too big for any screen, it d be around 150 inches, which I didn't find and if I did, I'm sure it'd cost more than a couple of thousands.

Comment: @PenguinSource -  You can buy bulk projection screen material at a reasonable price. [This site](http://www.carlofet.com/projector-screen-material/progray-projector-screen-raw-material.html) has 164" of mid-range screen material for less than $100. (they have higher end and lower end materials at different price points)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I saw a relevant thing at hackaday.com You can paint a large piece of hardboard and use that to cover the wall.

http://makeprojects.com/Project/Glass-Bead-Projection-Screen/685/1

Answer (score 1):

If you get some dry wall that is already formed you can cut it out in the size of the window and place it in the hole.  Once you have that slab in the hole you can go around the seam with dry-wall patch to make it blend in.  Once you have done both those things you can repaint the patch - or the entire wall to use it as your screen.

[Here is a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XQxGpcGGBk0) that shows what I am talking about - but on a smaller scale.  You would also probably want to put some insulation between the window and the new drywall you would be adding.

Alternatively you can search the web for a [150inch screen](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000NE35B4).  The one linked to is just the first thing that came up on amazon - I am not affiliated with it.  But I would guess that filling a hole that large would probably cost almost as much as that screen.